# Android Filtered ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, filtering, arrays

I take values of listview from an xml file. These are my java and xml codes:

```
package com.gazi.tezproje;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class verbs extends Activity {

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ActionBar bar=getActionBar(); 
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    MenuInflater menu1 = getMenuInflater();
    menu1.inflate(R.menu.info, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

       switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.menuinfo:
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.verbs), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  break; 
             case android.R.id.home:
                 finish();
                  break; }
    return false;
    }


private ListView vlist;
EditText ara;
private String [] fiilliste;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verbs);

        fiilliste=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fiiller);
        vlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fiilliste);
        vlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        ara = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        vlist.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

vlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,View v,int position,long id){          




    }


 }); 

 ara.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
          // When user changed the Text

         verbs.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 

      }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
 });

}}
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string-array name="fiiller">
        <item>A</item>
        <item>Affetmek</item>
        <item>Almak</item>
        <item>Anlamak</item>
        <item>Anlaşmak</item>
        <item>Anlatmak</item>
        <item>Ayrılmak</item>
        <item>B</item>
        <item>Bakmak</item>
        <item>Başlamak</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

For example; when I clicked on listview which is "Bakmak", I wanna show a text with toast, even when listview is filtered. And for other item of listview, another toast. I couldn't do it, because after filtering as you know, positions of items change.

I really need your ideas and help! Thank you!

Comment: whats the problem that positions change?

Comment: normally position of "Bakmak" is 8. When I filter listview for words which start "b", position changes from 8 to 2. I have problems about it.

Comment: what kind of problem?

Comment: when listview is not filtered, I can show a toast for "Bakmak". I'm using positions of items. but if I filtered listview, I can't show toast on correct item. 'switch(position){case 8: Toast.makeText...}' after filtering, it's not 8 anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the Adapter is filtered, Adapter should return the item from filtered list

Did you try this code?

```
    vlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,View v,int position,long id){          

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),adapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

 });
```

Comment: Thank you! This gives me idea to do what I want! So helpful.